# Java. Null meaning of object field

Tags: java, swing, null

I have some class, extended from JPanel. Here it's code.

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel{
    DrawingPanel(){
        mouseHandler=new MouseHandler(this);
        addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Point=mouseHandler.getPoint();
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (Point!=null){
            drawStartPoint(Point.getX(),Point.getY());
        }
        drawField();
    }
    private void drawField(){
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        for (int i=1;i<Main.COLUMNS;i++){
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(15*i,0,15*i,450));
        }
        for (int i=1;i<Main.ROWS;i++){
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(0,15*i,450,15*i));
        }
    }
    private void drawStartPoint(double x, double y){
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke((5)));
        DrawingPoint point=new DrawingPoint(Point.getX(),Point.getY());
        startPoint=new Point2D.Double(point.getX(),point.getY());
        Ellipse2D circlePoint= new Ellipse2D.Double(point.getX(),point.getY(),Main.DIAMETR_OF_CIRCLE,Main.DIAMETR_OF_CIRCLE);
        g2.fill(circlePoint);
        g2.draw(circlePoint);
    }
    public void drawDirectLineUp(){
        startPointsList.add(startPoint);
        finishPointsList.add(new Point2D.Double(startPoint.getX(),startPoint.getY()-15));
    }
    private ArrayList<Point2D> startPointsList=new ArrayList<Point2D>();
    private ArrayList<Point2D> finishPointsList=new ArrayList<Point2D>();
    private Graphics2D g2;
    private MouseHandler mouseHandler;
    private Point2D Point;
    private Point2D startPoint;
}
```

The panel is repainted every time, I click on it. Here is code of mouseHandler class.

```
public class MouseHandler implements MouseListener
{
    MouseHandler(DrawingPanel thePanel)
    {
        this.panel=thePanel;
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
    {
        Point=event.getPoint();
        panel.repaint();
    }

//Here is some auto-generated methods.
    public Point2D getPoint()
    {
        Point2D thePoint=this.Point;
        this.Point=null;
        return thePoint;
    }
    private Point2D Point;
    private DrawingPanel panel;
}
```

As you can see, every time I click on panel, paintComponent method is called, which calls drawStartPoint method, where startPoint field gets some value. But when I call drawDirectLineUp method, from actionListener of button placed on main panel, startPoint is null. Why it has null value again? How can I avoid it?

```
public class MainForm{
    MainForm(){
        createUIComponents();
        //adding items to comboBoxes
        directLineOkButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                switch (directDirectionCombobox.getSelectedIndex()){
                    case 0: ((DrawingPanel)drawingPanel).drawDirectLineUp();  break;
                    case 1: ((DrawingPanel)drawingPanel).drawDirectLineUp();  break;
                    case 2: ((DrawingPanel)drawingPanel).drawDirectLineUp();  break;
                    case 3: ((DrawingPanel)drawingPanel).drawDirectLineUp();  break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public JPanel getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }
    private void createUIComponents() {
           drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
    }
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JComboBox directDirectionCombobox;
    private JButton directLineOkButton;
    private JButton crossLineOkButton;
    private JComboBox crossLineComboBox;
    private JTextField crossLineSizeValue;
    private JButton clearButton;
    private JLabel directLineLabel;
    private JPanel directLinePanel;
    private JLabel crossLineLabel;
    private JPanel crossLinePanel;
    private JPanel okClearButtonPanel;
    private JTextField directLineSizeValue;
    private JButton saveButton;
    private JPanel drawingPanel;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Form");
        frame.setContentPane(new MainForm().getMainPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static final int ROWS=31;
    public static final int COLUMNS=31;
    public static final int DIAMETR_OF_CIRCLE=3;
}
```

Here is a stack trace of exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DrawingPanel.drawDirectLineUp(DrawingPanel.java:57)
    at MainForm$1.actionPerformed(MainForm.java:28)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Finally, I add .form XMl file.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns="http://www.intellij.com/uidesigner/form/" version="1" bind-to-class="MainForm">
  <grid id="27dc6" binding="mainPanel" layout-manager="FormLayout">
    <rowspec value="center:23px:noGrow"/>
    <rowspec value="top:3dlu:noGrow"/>
    <rowspec value="center:47px:noGrow"/>
    <rowspec value="top:3dlu:noGrow"/>
    <rowspec value="center:max(d;4px):noGrow"/>
    <rowspec value="top:3dlu:noGrow"/>
    <rowspec value="center:max(d;4px):noGrow"/>
    <rowspec value="top:7dlu:noGrow"/>
    <rowspec value="center:25px:noGrow"/>
    <rowspec value="top:174dlu:noGrow"/>
    <rowspec value="center:max(d;4px):noGrow"/>
    <colspec value="fill:d:noGrow"/>
    <colspec value="left:4dlu:noGrow"/>
    <colspec value="fill:452px:noGrow"/>
    <constraints>
      <xy x="20" y="20" width="741" height="453"/>
    </constraints>
    <properties/>
    <border type="none"/>
    <children>
      <component id="3b663" class="javax.swing.JLabel" binding="directLineLabel">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="0" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="0" anchor="8" fill="0" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
          <forms/>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <text value="Direct Line"/>
        </properties>
      </component>
      <grid id="499e0" binding="directLinePanel" layout-manager="FormLayout">
        <rowspec value="center:d:grow"/>
        <colspec value="fill:98px:noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="left:4dlu:noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="fill:80px:grow"/>
        <colspec value="left:4dlu:noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="fill:max(d;4px):noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="left:4dlu:noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="fill:max(d;4px):noGrow"/>
        <constraints>
          <grid row="1" column="0" row-span="2" col-span="1" vsize-policy="3" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="3" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
          <forms/>
        </constraints>
        <properties/>
        <border type="none"/>
        <children>
          <component id="c383d" class="javax.swing.JComboBox" binding="directDirectionCombobox">
            <constraints>
              <grid row="0" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="2" anchor="8" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
              <forms/>
            </constraints>
            <properties>
              <enabled value="true"/>
            </properties>
          </component>
          <component id="17aa1" class="javax.swing.JTextField" binding="directLineSizeValue">
            <constraints>
              <grid row="0" column="2" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="6" anchor="8" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false">
                <preferred-size width="150" height="-1"/>
              </grid>
              <forms defaultalign-horz="false"/>
            </constraints>
            <properties/>
          </component>
          <component id="44fc7" class="javax.swing.JButton" binding="directLineOkButton">
            <constraints>
              <grid row="0" column="4" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
              <forms/>
            </constraints>
            <properties>
              <text value="OK"/>
            </properties>
          </component>
        </children>
      </grid>
      <component id="5a571" class="javax.swing.JLabel" binding="crossLineLabel">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="4" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="0" anchor="8" fill="0" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
          <forms/>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <text value="Cross Line"/>
        </properties>
      </component>
      <grid id="77f1a" binding="crossLinePanel" layout-manager="FormLayout">
        <rowspec value="center:d:grow"/>
        <colspec value="fill:98px:noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="left:4dlu:noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="fill:80px:grow"/>
        <colspec value="left:4dlu:noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="fill:max(d;4px):noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="left:4dlu:noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="fill:max(d;4px):noGrow"/>
        <constraints>
          <grid row="6" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="3" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="3" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
          <forms/>
        </constraints>
        <properties/>
        <border type="none"/>
        <children>
          <component id="32368" class="javax.swing.JComboBox" binding="crossLineComboBox">
            <constraints>
              <grid row="0" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="2" anchor="8" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
              <forms/>
            </constraints>
            <properties/>
          </component>
          <component id="dbf23" class="javax.swing.JTextField" binding="crossLineSizeValue">
            <constraints>
              <grid row="0" column="2" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="6" anchor="8" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false">
                <preferred-size width="150" height="-1"/>
              </grid>
              <forms defaultalign-horz="false"/>
            </constraints>
            <properties/>
          </component>
          <component id="c5c8a" class="javax.swing.JButton" binding="crossLineOkButton">
            <constraints>
              <grid row="0" column="4" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
              <forms/>
            </constraints>
            <properties>
              <text value="OK"/>
            </properties>
          </component>
        </children>
      </grid>
      <grid id="53bbc" binding="okClearButtonPanel" layout-manager="FormLayout">
        <rowspec value="center:d:noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="fill:d:noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="left:4dlu:noGrow"/>
        <colspec value="fill:max(d;4px):noGrow"/>
        <constraints>
          <grid row="8" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="3" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="3" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
          <forms/>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <enabled value="false"/>
        </properties>
        <border type="none"/>
        <children>
          <component id="41ba7" class="javax.swing.JButton" binding="saveButton">
            <constraints>
              <grid row="0" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
              <forms/>
            </constraints>
            <properties>
              <text value="Save"/>
            </properties>
          </component>
          <component id="a6bf6" class="javax.swing.JButton" binding="clearButton">
            <constraints>
              <grid row="0" column="2" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
              <forms/>
            </constraints>
            <properties>
              <text value="Clear"/>
            </properties>
          </component>
        </children>
      </grid>
      <grid id="2e94e" binding="drawingPanel" custom-create="true" layout-manager="FormLayout">
        <rowspec value="center:d:grow"/>
        <colspec value="fill:d:grow"/>
        <constraints>
          <grid row="0" column="2" row-span="11" col-span="1" vsize-policy="3" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="3" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
          <forms/>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <background color="-1"/>
        </properties>
        <border type="none"/>
        <children/>
      </grid>
    </children>
  </grid>
</form>
```

[image: Strange bug]

Comment: You haven't posted the parts of your code that are relevant for concurrency analysis. Try making `startPoint` `volatile` and see if that fixes the immediate problem.

Comment: Edited it now, add 2 classes, tried to make it volatile, but it works the same way.

Comment: I set it in drawStartPoint method.

Comment: As a minor point, if you're creating `drawingPanel`, make the field of that type instead of `JPanel`. It's clearer, and you won't have to make the casts everywhere.

Comment: Well, I create form via Intelij Idea GUI designer. So when I make type DrawingPanel it says about mistake.

Comment: Now I added stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like instantiation problem, `DrawingPanel` was created twice. Also, method `createUIComponents` was called twice - once in constructor and by `MainForm.form` (looks like it is standard method or something like this), so we had two separate instances.

The solution is removing redundant `createUIComponents` call

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void drawDirectLineUp(){
        if(startPoint!=null){  //Please ensure do you have initialized startPoint properly .
            startPointsList.add(startPoint);
            finishPointsList.add(new Point2D.Double(startPoint.getX(),startPoint.getY()-15));
        }               
   }
```

Comment: I've added this condition, but didn't fix mistake, the field is still null.

Comment: You need to initialize like this startPoint=new Point2D.Double(point.getX(),point.getY());

Comment: @Prabhakaran He's doing that in `drawStartPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, that the variable drawingPanel in the ActionListener of your button does not point to the same DrawingPanel you clicked?

And it's true that if you first click your button before you click into your panel, the variable startPoint is still null.

Comment: I initialize it once at createUIComponents(), so I think drawingPanel is the same. 
I click button after I click panel. And when I click panel the variable is not null.

Comment: Where and how do you add your drawingPanel to your contentPane? I'm missing this part... If you don't add it, you can't click it and startPoint never has a value != null.

Comment: Well, I added it via GUI designer of intelij idea.

Comment: Added a .form xml now.

Comment: Now I tested your code myself (without intelliJ) and it works aslong as i click first into the DrawingPanel! If startPoint once is != null it cannot become null again unless on another instance of DrawingPanel...

Comment: I've just clicked Drawing panel, than put some value at TextField. When I click OK button and watch it in debuger, the startPoint is null.

Comment: Now I even posted a picture. As you can see field is clicked (point mark appeared), but at the debugger startPoint is null.

Comment: This is very strange... Did you check if DrawingPanel is the same instance on click as on button press? You see this in the debugger by checking the number in DrawindPanel@1549. You never assign startPoint = null

Answer (score 0):

Every time `paintComponent` is called, it is calling `mouseHandler.getPoint()`, which is setting `Point` to `null`.  This value is then assigned to `startPoint`.

`paintComponent` can be called for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control.

You be better off adding the `startPoint` directly to your list (when the mouse is clicked), repainting the component each time

Do you realise, your example doesn't appear to be adding anything to the frame and would probably throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: But there is an condition there if (Point!=null), so drawPoint is called only when it's not null.
What you mean about no adding anything to frame?

Comment: I gonna make 2 arrays with coordinates and draw some lines every repaint.